# Change the displayed row in crystal reports c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, crystal-reports

I have to print a report of a clients details using my c# program. I use a access database to store the client details. I've successfully created and displayed the report on my form in my c# application. Now I'm struggling to change the displayed row for the report. The report automatically chooses the first row in my database. I've created the crystal report without coding, I used the crystal reports visual studio plugin therefore can't paste any code.

Comment: Maybe you should show some code...

Comment: Use ODBC connection then command in Crystal Report